# Adding to list overwrites previous object values in C#

Tags: c#, foreach

Although there are several posts on Stackoverflow about this kind of issue, then I have looked through them and have not found a solution for my problem.

In the code, I am going going through a list of lists with a foreach loop and adding created elements to another list. Although in the foreach loop each iteration gives an unique value, then outside of it the values are the same.

```
try
{
    List<Takeoff> takeoffs = new List<Takeoff>();

    List<List<String>> itemTable = queryTable("TK_ITEM", 52);

    foreach (List<String> row in itemTable)
    {
        // Second element in the constructor is Name.
        Takeoff takeoff = new Takeoff(row.ElementAt(0), row.ElementAt(3), row.ElementAt(11), 
            row.ElementAt(17), row.ElementAt(25), row.ElementAt(33), 
            row.ElementAt(37), row.ElementAt(45));

        MessageBox.Show(row.ElementAt(3)); // Each iteration gives an unique value.

        takeoffs.Add(takeoff);
    }

    // Values of both objects are the same.
    MessageBox.Show(takeoffs[0].Name);
    MessageBox.Show(takeoffs[1].Name);

    return takeoffs;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No material takeoff created!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

    return null;
}
```

I have tried various methods of adding and displaying the values, but so far I have not found a solution which would work.

Could anyone point out to me where the problem is?

Edit: Declaration of takeoff

```
/*...*/
private static string name;
/*...*/

public Takeoff(string id, string name, string guid, string width, string height, string area, string volume, string count)
{
    /*...*/
    Name = name;
    /*...*/
}

/*...*/

public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value; }
}

/*...*/
```

Comment: Can you show the type `Takeoff`, including its `Name` property or field and its constructor?

Comment: Can you show Takeoff ctor?

Comment: As a side-note, consider reducing the number of parameters needed to pass to the `TakeOff` constructor. Maybe use property initialisation e.g. `var takeOff = new TakeOff { Name = "Blah" };` Having to pass 8 parameters is a major maintenance headache waiting to happen.

Comment: For sanity, instead of doing `MessageBox.Show(row.ElementAt(3));` in the loop why not display `takeoff.Name`? If you "know" `row.ElementAt(3)` is correct then you need to check if the construction of `takeoff` is.

Comment: At the very least create local variables with appropriate names for all those parameters, it is hard to reason about the code when you see `row.ElementAt(45)`, and you got to go look at the constructor of `Takeoff` to see what that is supposed to be. A simple `var idOfParentObject = row.ElementAt(45);` is going to help a lot.

Comment: Added the declaration of takeoff to the topic.

Comment: As I suspected you have a static backing field. Static = 1 per type, not 1 per instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `name` backing field is static:

```
private static string name;
```

Don't do that. Just remove the `static` modifier, it's not necessary.

[Static members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) belong to the *type*, rather than the instance. This means all instances of `Takeoff` share the same value of `name`, whichever value was assigned last.

Comment: And I am one thousand percent certain this has at least one exact duplicate, but I couldn't find one with this specific problem.

Comment: Thank you, did not even notice that. Now that you pointed it out, it is obvious.

Comment: @CodeCaster, it's off-topic as it's a trivial typo. Just needs closing for that reason. No need to hunt for duplicates.

Comment: @David adding a modifier is not a typo. It is a fundamental misunderstanding of what `static` does, and warrants explanation.

Comment: @CodeCaster, it's unlikely to be of any help to anyone but the OP though. As per "While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers", it's justifed in closing it as a simple typo.